# How to test whether 2 arrays contain the same elements in zsh / Unix shell?

Tags: shell, zsh

What is the right way to test whether 2 zsh arrays are structurally equal, i.e., contain the same elements?

`[[ $array1 == $array2 ]]` passes a few tests but I don't know whether it's the correct form and I can't seem to find the topic discussed anywhere.

I'm writing zsh code at the moment but I'm also interested in a portable answer (bash/POSIX) if different.

Comment: switching debug on shows that with [[ $array1 == $array2 ]], they are compared as joined strings, if I'm not mistaken. I.e. `array1=(a b c)` will be equal to `array2=('a b' c)`

Comment: `$array1` is the same as `${array1[0]}` (for bash at least)

Comment: For "equal" arrays, do you care if the elements are in the same order? Is `(a b c)` equal to `(c a b)`?

Comment: @glennjackman They're not the same in zsh though.

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, I do care about order, I want (a b) and (b a) to be different. A value can appear multiple times in an array too.

Comment: `zsh` is like `bash` in that there is no such thing as an array "value"; it's all just syntax trickery to simulate groups of related variables under one name.

Comment: @chepner I feel like shell scripting as a whole blurs the line between sound implementation and syntax trickery... Is the data structure underlying arrays worth knowing?

Comment: I would loop over the arrays and compare them element-by-element. If you really want to have code which works the same in bash and zsh (why?), don't forget that - among others - array indexing is different in those languages.

Comment: @Nahoj That's kind of unanswerable, because there *is* no underlying data structure that you can access at runtime. In an expression like `${arr[3]}`, `arr[3]` is essentially just a weirdly spelled identifier. This interpretation is reinforced by the interaction with indirect parameter expansion: `t="arr[3]"; echo ${!t}` works like `echo ${arr[3]}`. In general, just about every aspect of shell syntax you might find weird is the result of the decision to make an external command executable by simply using its name *as* the command. (1/2)

Comment: That is, there is no special syntax (or rather, the most basic syntax is used) for invoking a command, nor is there a special function to run an external command. (2/2)

Comment: @user1934428 I don't particularly need code that works the same in bash and zsh, I just needed a zsh solution right now and am also interested in how to do it in bash/POSIX, should I need it on another occasion.
Before I looked for it, I expected the answer to be something along the lines of "In zsh just use (($array1@{{=}}$array2)), but if you want a more portable solution you have to use the old POSIX syntax [[array1!@!{]eq[!}array2]] which is also valid zsh".

Comment: I would follow the same algorithm for bash, but if you would get problems in implementing it in  bash,  just ask here a new question. At Stackoverflow, one question should be focus on a single problem (typically involving only one programming language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic function that compares two array variables element by element:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

# Takes the names of two array variables
arrayeq() {
    typeset -i i len

    # The P parameter expansion flag treats the parameter as a name of a
    # variable to use
    len=${#${(P)1}} 

    if [[ $len -ne ${#${(P)2}} ]]; then
       return 1
    fi

    # Remember zsh arrays are 1-indexed
    for (( i = 1; i <= $len; i++)); do
        if [[ ${(P)1[i]} != ${(P)2[i]} ]]; then
            return 1
        fi
    done
}

arr1=(1 apple 3 4)
arr2=(1 apple 4 5)

if arrayeq arr1 arr2; then
    print They match
else
    print They are different
fi
```

Comment: I think this fits my needs, thank you. Should I be surprised not to find an existing answer to this? This seems like such a basic need to me; I expected modern shells to have built-in syntax for this.

Comment: @Nahoj Any time I've needed to do it I've been using a more capable language. Arrays are a bit of pain to work with in shell.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the arrays will not contain `null` (and very, very few shell values have a `null`), you can use that as a delimiter to compare the joined versions of the arrays:

```bash
if [[ ${(pj:\0:)ary1} == ${(pj:\0:)ary2} ]]; then ...
```

As a function:

```bash
cmpArrays() {
  [[ ${(Ppj:\0:)1:?} == ${(Ppj:\0:)2:?} ]]
}
```

Testing:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

tst() {
  if cmpArrays $1 $2; then
    result=match
  else
    result=nomatch
  fi
  if [[ $result == $3 ]]; then
    print $1 $2 $3 pass
  else
    print $1 $2 $3 FAIL
  fi
}

a1=(a b c)
a2=(a b c)
a3=(a b c d)
a4=('a b' c)
a5=(a c b)
a6=(a b '' c)

tst a1 a2 match
tst a1 a3 nomatch
tst a1 a4 nomatch
tst a1 a5 nomatch
tst a1 a6 nomatch
```

Test output:

```bash
a1 a2 match pass
a1 a3 nomatch pass
a1 a4 nomatch pass
a1 a5 nomatch pass
a1 a6 nomatch pass
```

The `j` and `P` flags are described in the [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) section of the `zsh` documentation.

Comment: Thank you, this also fits my needs and might come in handy, as I'm dealing with very safe values, though I tend to prefer the most general and algorithmically correct solution.

Comment: The `p` flag is also needed (`pj:\0:`) otherwise `\0` is not a NUL but just "\0"

Comment: @rowboat Updated - thanks! I had tested the joins with `print` and `xxd`, but it looks like I forgot to use `print -r` :-(.